# How to stop creating instance of Singleton

Tags: java, singleton

I have a Singleton class like this:

```
class Singleton {
    static class SingletonHolder {
        static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Can I call like this from other class:

```
Singleton dummy = new Singleton();
```

if yes how can I disable it? if not, then why cannot i?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.  Just make the constructor private to avoid that: just add `private Singleton() {}` to prevent the default constructor from being public.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you make it an `enum` (since they can't be instantiated anyway);

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Comment: well I'm against using enum for singleton. but it has been discussed too many times:)